# SQL queries in MySQL using phpseclib

Tags: php, mysql, phpseclib

I am trying to connect to MySQL database on a remote server and I could successfully connect to the server and login to the MySQL database. But now i need to run few SQL queries on the database tables but facing the error : ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES).

I am not sure if the SQL queries are of correct syntax? Also do i need to connect to the server every time i need to run SQL queries? Please provide me with some inputs. Thanks.

```
 /* SUCCESS */
 $ssh = new Net_SSH2('XX.XXX.XX.XXX');
     if (!$ssh->login('root', 'password')) {
     exit('Login Failed');
  }

 echo $ssh->exec('pwd');

  /* SUCCESS */
  if (!$ssh->exec('mysql -h localhost -u root -pDataBaseName \r\n')){
        exit('Login to MySQL Failed');
  }else{
        echo "Login to MySQL Success";
  }

 /* ERROR - facing error in this code*/
  echo $ssh->exec('mysql -h localhost -u root -pDataBaseName -e "SELECT * FROM cmu_util_all"');
```

Comment: `-pDataBaseName` doesn't mean that DataBaseName is the DB that mysql is connecting to - it means that you're using DataBaseName as the password. If that's your intention that's fine but it seems like that could be a mistake on your part too..

Answer (score 0):

Your `SELECT` statement doesn't specify the database to be used.

```
mysql -h localhost -u root -pDataBaseName -e "SELECT * FROM cmu_util_all"
```

You can fix this either by specifying the database in the query:

```
SELECT * FROM yourdatabase.cmu_util_all
```

or by specifying the default database to be used for the connection:

```
mysql -h localhost -u root -pDataBaseName -e "SELECT * FROM cmu_util_all" yourdatabase
```

Comment: I am still facing the error : ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)